# spark get minimum value in column that satisfies a condition

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in spark that looks like this:

```
id |  flag
----------
 0 |  true
 1 |  true
 2 | false
 3 |  true
 4 |  true
 5 |  true
 6 | false
 7 | false
 8 |  true
 9 | false
```

I want to get another Column with the current rowNumber if it has `flag == false`, or the rowNumber of the next false value, so the output would be like this:

```
id |  flag | nextOrCurrentFalse
-------------------------------
 0 |  true |                  2
 1 |  true |                  2
 2 | false |                  2
 3 |  true |                  6
 4 |  true |                  6
 5 |  true |                  6
 6 | false |                  6
 7 | false |                  7
 8 |  true |                  9
 9 | false |                  9
```

I want to do this in a vectorized way (not iterating by row). So I effectively want the logic to be:

- For each row, get the min id greater than or equal to the current rowNum which has a flag == false

Comment: I always wonder about the performance of such things. How many entries do you have? I presume you mean vectorized way as in not in SQL. I would not attempt SQL here.

Comment: In addition, with partitioning aspects I suspect some errors would result.

Comment: no actually, an SQL solution would be perfect. I just don't want one that relies on iterating through the dataset (which is probably way more efficient in this case, but I don't want to do that because I want to extend this to other use cases where I can't do that).

Comment: Tell me how many rows?

Comment: I'm not really concerned about performance, but let's just say I have 1 million rows.

Comment: I find it an interesting use case that I will try, I will provide an answer shortly - I think. But not happy on performance, so deal would need to be to tell me how long  it took.

Comment: Sure. In fact, if you can find a faster iterative way, I'd also be interested in comparing the two. It's just that I want to know in general how to "vectorize" these sort of calculations for the future. By "vectorize" I mean that you can compute each row's result in parallel, and that each row is independent of the calculation of the previous rows.

Comment: That latter will be for tomorrow, but I am thinking of the partitioning DF aspects that could cause issues. The results may not be 100% correct. This SQL will run like a dog. Nearly there.

Comment: Can you check your 2 false 2 entry - that seems a mistake

Comment: At leats the definition of next is not correct

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. If the current row is false, it returns that row. Otherwise, it returns the next row after that which has flag == false.

Comment: that is no big deal but performance is

Comment: I am posting a better answer shortly, expecting some kudos!

Comment: I am using this to check how good Catalyst and such really is in the next few weeks - at scale of course.

Comment: would be really interested to see that research. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having thought about scaling and such - but not clear whether Catalyst is good enough - I propose a solution that builds on one of the answers that could benefit from partitioning and has far less work to do - simply by thinking about the data. It's about pre-computation and processing, the point that some massaging can beat brute force approaches. Your point on JOIN is less of an issue as this is a bounded JOIN now and no massive generation of data.

Your comment on dataframe approach is slightly jaded in that all that has surpassed here are dataframes. I think you mean that you want to loop through a Data Frame and have a sub loop with an exit. I can find no such example and in fact I am not sure it fits the SPARK paradigm. Same results gotten, with less processing:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq((0, true), (1, true), (2,false), (3, true), (4,true), (5,true), (6,false), (7,false), (8,true), (9,false)).toDF("id","flag")
@transient val  w1 = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("id1")  

val ids = df.where("flag = false") 
            .select($"id".as("id1"))  

val ids2 = ids.select($"*", lag("id1",1,-1).over(w1).alias("prev_id"))
val ids3 = ids2.withColumn("prev_id1", col("prev_id")+1).drop("prev_id")

// Less and better performance at scale, this is better theoretically for Catalyst to bound partitions? Less work to do in any event.
// Some understanding of data required! And no grouping and min.
val withNextFalse = df.join(ids3, df("id") >= ids3("prev_id1") && df("id") <= ids3("id1"))
                     .select($"id", $"flag", $"id1".alias("nextOrCurrentFalse"))
                     .orderBy(asc("id"),asc("id"))

withNextFalse.show(false)
```

returns also:

```
+---+-----+------------------+
|id |flag |nextOrCurrentFalse|
+---+-----+------------------+
|0  |true |2                 |
|1  |true |2                 |
|2  |false|2                 |
|3  |true |6                 |
|4  |true |6                 |
|5  |true |6                 |
|6  |false|6                 |
|7  |false|7                 |
|8  |true |9                 |
|9  |false|9                 |
+---+-----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If `flag` is fairly sparse, you could do it like this:

```
val ids = df.where("flag = false"). 
             select($"id".as("id1"))  

val withNextFalse = df.join(ids, df("id") <= ids("id1")).
                      groupBy("id", "flag").
                      agg("id1" -> "min")
```

In the first step, we make a dataframe of the ids where the flag is false.  Then, we join that dataframe to the original data on the desired condition (the original id should be less than or equal to the id of the row where flag is false).

To get the *first* such case, group by id and use `agg` to find the minimum value of `id1` (which is the id of a row with flag = false.

Running on your example data (and sorting on id) gives the desired output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
| id| flag|min(id1)|
+---+-----+--------+
|  0| true|       2|
|  1| true|       2|
|  2|false|       2|
|  3| true|       6|
|  4| true|       6|
|  5| true|       6|
|  6|false|       6|
|  7|false|       7|
|  8| true|       9|
|  9|false|       9|
+---+-----+--------+
```

This approach could run into performance trouble if the DataFrame is very large and has many rows where the flag is False.  If that's the case, you may be better off with an iterative solution.

Comment: Great answer! But you're right. This is a bit too resource heavy. Was hoping to find a way to do this without a join. This is something that is simple in MATLAB with smaller data sets. I really want to know how it would be done in spark with DataFrames.

Comment: @Jason Embellished your answer in more than one way

Comment: It's an interesting problem that got a -2 and turned out to be easy to solve - that said I had to brood on it.

Answer (score 0):

See other answer which is better , but left this here so for SQL educational purposes - possibly.

This does what you want, but I would be keen to know what others thinks of this at scale. I am going to check Catalyst and see how it works procedurally, but I think that may mean some misses at partition bounaries, I am keen to check that as well.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq((0, true), (1, true), (2,false), (3, true), (4,true), (5,true), (6,false), (7,false), (8,true), (9,false)).toDF("id","flag")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tf") 

// Performance? Need to check at some stage how partitioning works in such a case.
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE tf") 
val res1 = spark.sql("""  
                       SELECT tf1.*, tf2.id as id2, tf2.flag as flag2
                         FROM tf tf1, tf tf2
                        WHERE tf2.id  >= tf1.id
                          AND tf2.flag = false 
                     """)    

//res1.show(false)
res1.createOrReplaceTempView("res1") 
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE res1") 

val res2 = spark.sql(""" SELECT X.id, X.flag, X.id2 
                           FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id2 ASC) as rank_val 
                                   FROM res1) X
                          WHERE X.rank_val = 1
                       ORDER BY id
                    """) 

res2.show(false)
```

Comment: Like the other solution better actually, but the performance issue is noted as well.